# 2й максимальный элемент в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы

подскажите как найти наибольший элемент массива после максимального? например при:

```
             [5,5] или [5] - null;
             [1,2,3] - 2; 
             [5,5,4,1] - 4;
             [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-5] - (-2);
```

код:

```
var array = [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-5];

function main(array){
  max = array[0];
  afterMax = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (max < array[i]) {
      afterMax = max;
      max = array[i];
    }
    else if(max != array[i] && afterMax < array[i]){
      afterMax = array[i];
    }
  }
  console.log(afterMax);
}

main(array);
```

Comment: если есть элемент больший чем максимальный, значит максимальный - не максимальный

Comment: что не работает в вашем коде?

Comment: ой точно))
не могу добиться выполнения последнего кейса,чтоб не поломать предыдущие

[-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-5] - (-2);

Comment: а вот на этом примере проходит? `[5,5,4,1]` они должны одинаково работать

Comment: Проходит. Может дело в отрицательных числах?
null не меньше чем 0, я думаю поэтому и не работает на том кейсе(

Comment: не, они по тем же правилам сравниваются

Comment: null не меньше чем 0, я думаю поэтому и не работает на том кейсе( 

как обыграть этот момент я не могу сообразить

Comment: да вы правы, при сравнении null с отрицательным числом всегда false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример однострочного решения

```
Math.max.apply(Math,array.filter(function(el){return el < Math.max.apply(Math,array);}))
```

Суть: ищем максимальный элемент, фильтруем его, и снова ищем максимум, это и будет требуемое значение.

Что касается вашего вариант, то стоит заменить `null` На `-Infinity` начальное значение. Правда, тогда нужно будет добавить проверку в конце, чтобы вернуть `null`.
И еще одно замечание: использовать локальные переменные `max`, `aftermax`

```js
var array = [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-5];

function main(array){
  var max = array[0];
  var afterMax = -Infinity;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (max < array[i]) {
      afterMax = max;
      max = array[i];
    }
    else if(max != array[i] && afterMax < array[i]){
      afterMax = array[i];
    }
  }
  console.log(afterMax === -Infinity ? null : afterMax);
}

main(array);
```

Еще вариант просто добавить проверку на `null` перед сравнением

```js
var array = [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -5];

function main(array) {
  var max = array[0],
    afterMax = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (max < array[i]) {
      afterMax = max;
      max = array[i];
    } else if (max != array[i] && (afterMax == null || afterMax < array[i])) {
      afterMax = array[i];
    }
  }
  console.log(afterMax);
}

main(array);
```

И еще вариант с reduce

```js
var array = [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -5];

function main(array) {
  var afterMax = array.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
    switch (acc.length) {
      case 0:
        acc.push(cur);
        break;
      case 1:
        if (acc[0] > cur) acc.push(cur)
        else if (acc[0] < cur) acc.unshift(cur);
        break;
      default:
        if (acc[0] < cur) acc.unshift(cur)
        else if (acc[0] > cur && acc[1] < cur) acc[1] = curr;
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])[1];
  console.log(afterMax);
}

main(array);
```

Comment: Асимптотика квадратичная получается...

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага, поэтому я не сказал что это оптимальное решение, а однострочник :-)

Comment: @Qwertiy, а почему кстати квадратичная? зависит вроде от реализации max, нет?

Comment: Потому что для каждого элемента максимум ищется заново.

Comment: А что не так с max? Он работает за линейное время и быстрее не может.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а, это к max, который внутри фильтра? это да, стоило его вынести, но так красивее смотрелось :-D

Comment: Ага.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/490679/178988 :D

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение ошибок и ваш вариант решения ;)

Comment: @DenisOleshchenko, в принципе-то у вас решение правильное было, одной проверки на null не хватало

Answer (score 5):

сортируем массив по возрастанию, находим первое максимальное число, слева от него искомое или нет ничего.

```js
 function fn(a) {
   a = a.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
     return a - b
   });
   return a[a.indexOf(Math.max.apply(null, a)) - 1]
 };
 alert(fn([-1, -2, -5, -25, -125])); //-2
 alert(fn([1, 1, 5, 5])); //1
 alert(fn([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5])); //4
 alert(fn([5, 5])) // undefined;
 alert(fn([1, 2, 3])) // 2;
 alert(fn([5, 5, 4, 1])) // 4;
 alert(fn([-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -5])) // -2;
```

Answer (score 3):

Один раз пробежаться по элементам, сохраняя два значения: максимальное и следующее за ним.

```js
function secondMax(a) {
  var m0, m1;
  for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    if( typeof m0 === 'undefined') {
      m0 = a[i];
    } else if( m0 < a[i]) {
      m1 = m0;
      m0 = a[i];
    } else if( typeof m1 === 'undefined'  &&  m0 > a[i]) {
      m1 = a[i];
    } else if( m1 <= a[i]  &&  m0 > a[i]) {
      m1 = a[i];
    }
  }
  return m1;
}

var tests = [
 [[-1, -2, -5, -25, -125], -2]
,[[1, 1, 5, 5], 1]
,[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5], 4]
,[[5, 5], undefined]
,[[1, 2, 3], 2]
,[[5, 5, 4, 1], 4]
,[[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -5], -2]
];

tests.map(function(e){
  var result = secondMax(e[0]);
  document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(e[0]) + " "
 + (result == e[1] ? "passed" : "failed: " + result) + '<br>';})
```

Comment: что-то у нас у всех варианты как будто минификатором и обфускатором прошлись :-D

Answer (score 1):

Линейный (кажется) однострочный, ES6.

```
f=a=>Math.max(...`,${a},`.replace(RegExp(`,${Math.max(...a)}(?=,)`,'g'),'').slice(1,-1).split`,`)
```

PS: Не надо обращать внимания на этот ответ :)

Comment: JS потерял всю прелесть своей синтаксической простоты и красоты!